# Probability of having only two roommates made of A and B

Tags: probability

This is my question:
A basketball team consists of 6 frontcourt and 4 backcourt players. If players are divided into roommates at random, what is the probability that there will be exactly two roommate pairs made up of a backcourt and a frontcourt player?

I tried solving it this way: I supposed I have two 5 sided dices(because we have 5 rooms) and I calculated the probability of having the same number for both dices after rolling for two times. 
But my answer is wrong. I have the solution but I can't understand it at all. Can anybody explain this step by step? What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Well there can only be 0, 2 or 4 rooms with different types of players in them. I have a suspicion that it would be easier to calculate 0 and 4 and subtract that from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first issue with your approach is that nothing in your approach seems to care whether we have 4 frontcourt players, or only 2, or 8.

Instead, let's consider the ten places as:

```
room1BunkA  room1BunkB
room2BunkA  room2BunkB
room3BunkA  room3BunkB
room4BunkA  room4BunkB
room5BunkA  room5BunkB
```

And imagine us labeling each place with a `F` or `B` depending on whether a frontcourt or backcourt player is staying there. For example:

```
F B
B B
F F
B F
B B
```

This would be one of the situations we want to count, since there are two rooms with both a frontcourt and a backcourt player in them.

Now, there are
$$
\binom{10}{4} = \frac{10!}{4!6!} = 210
$$
ways to label 4 of the 10 slots with an `F` (labeling the rest with a `B`). How many of those assignments will result in exactly two mixed-court rooms?

Well, if we have two mixed rooms, then we'll have two mixed rooms, one all-`F` room, and two all-`B` rooms. The number of ways to choose those rooms is:

$$
\frac{5!}{2!1!2!} = 30
$$

Furthermore, once we've chosen which rooms will be which, there are four ways to label the bunks in the two mixed rooms (each room can be either `F B` or `B F`), so all told there are $120$ ways to label slots with `F` and `B` that result in two mixed rooms. Therefore, the probability is $120/210$ or $4/7$.